# Do not synchronize on objects that may be reused

Tags: java

Why it is a bad practice to synchronize on the object which are changable.
How they lead to deadlock ?

For ex ::

```
private int count = 0;
private final Integer Lock = count; // Boxed primitive Lock is shared

public void doSomething() {
  synchronized (Lock) {
   count++;
   // ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Who says so? It's very common to synchronize on `this` for example (even if it's not always advisable).

Comment: And how often does `this` typically change inside the calling class? ;-)

Comment: The question is not so well formed. After the edit, it seems the OP is asking whether primitive wrappers can be used as monitors.

Comment: I read somewhere that if any other code were to inadvertently synchronize on a Integer literal with this value, the lock instance would be reused and the system could become unresponsive or could deadlock

Comment: that's true, integer literals get cached and the same object instance could be acquired by separate otherwise-unrelated sections of code, so that one section of code could stop the other from working by keeping it from acquiring the lock it needs. actually in your example the Lock is not changeable, it remains at 0 and doesn't reflect changes in count. My answer to the linked question also addresses why you shouldn't change the lock.